# FIWARE - Keyrock new user without access

Tags: fiware, keystone, identity-management, identitymanager

We want to add users at our local instance of keyrock. Now, we only have the default idm user. When we create a new user, a confirmation email should be sent, but this is not happening. In this case, the new user is not validated and therefore he/she can not access the service.

What is supposed to do for using new users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the GUI of KeyRock and that you are in a **production** environment, you must set up a SMTP server to send it (as it is stated in the [KeyRock Documentation](http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#email-configuration)). In case you haven't done so, let me give you some hints on how to set set up a mail server using POSTFIX and connect the front-end of KeyRock to it. Further information can be found in the Django documentation.

1. Install and configure POSTFIX. In Ubuntu, you should run:

   `sudo apt-get install postfix`
2. Edit the **`local_settings.py`** file (the one inside `horizon/openstack_dashboard/local/`) to configure the new email backend:

   ```py
   EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
   ```

   This will get the settings from the default SMTP server in your host (it should be POSTFIX after installing it).

   In case you are not running POSTFIX in the same host or want to use a different configuration, make use of the following settings:

   ```py
   # Configure these for your outgoing email host
   EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.my-company.com'
   EMAIL_PORT = 25
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'djangomail'
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'top-secret!'
   EMAIL_URL = 'your-webstie-domain.com'
   DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your-no-reply-address'
   EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Prefix for emails subject]'
   ```

In case you are in a **development** environment, Django outputs emails to the console, so you may find the link to activate the user's account right in your Horizon console.

Hope this helps! Feel free to write back otherwise.

Kind regards from the KeyRock Team!

EDIT: the newer versions of Keyrock IdM do not list the activation link in the logs. Here it is: `host_address:3000/activate?activation_key=your_activation_key&email=your_email`. Change `your_activation_key` and `your_email` with your data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Federico . We are running the keyrock in a docker container. When we start the container, the services are already running. Could you please tell me where I can find the output of the Horizon console? Is there some specific log?

Comment: Hi! I am not a Docker expert, but from my experience I can tell you that docker shows logs on the console unless you run the container in the background. If this is your case, I guess the `docker logs <container>` command should work for you.